# Zip file not deleted in mule

Tags: mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

I am reading a zip file using file inbound connector in mule. The file should be auto deleted, since auto delete is true. But it's not. 
The flow I have is

`<file:connector name="File" writeToDirectory="D:\FileProcessed\ringmoved\"      readFromDirectory="D:\FileProcessed\" autoDelete="true" streaming="true"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<flow name="filFlow">
<file:inbound-endpoint path="D:\FileProcessed\" moveToDirectory="D:\FileProcessed\moved\" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
<logger message="hi" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not consuming the file. Try adding a transformer such as

```
<object-to-string-transformer />
```

after the file endpoint.

Comment: if I put a java component after file connector,will it consume file or not? The java class will unzip the file picked.

Comment: @abhay, Whenever you are using file related connector in streaming mode. It will not delete the file unless stream is processed and closed. You can so any kind of processing like conversion to String, Byte Array or unzip with java component. it will delete the file.